# Jquery won't recognize variables

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have some attributes that I am trying to change with the `.css` in jquery but for some reason the code does not work. Is there something wrong with the parenthesis?

the original value is set as so `padding: 40px 0 0;`

here is the jquery that changes the above value:

```
var header = $('#main'),
    padding = '40px';

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() <= padding / 2) {
        header.css({
            'padding-top': -($(this).scrollTop() - padding) + "px",
            'padding-bottom': -($(this).scrollTop() - padding) + "px"
        });
```

Comment: What error are you receiving in your browser's console?

Comment: @kyle.stearns not receiving one the console is blank

Comment: You need to show more code

Comment: I don't know about the parentheses, but you can't have negative values in the `padding`; they're invalid lengths and will be discarded by the browser.

Comment: Syntax looks fine, not enough to go on.

Comment: here is more code added to the question

Comment: the padding needs to decrease as the window scrolls down that is the reason for the negative

Comment: Are you sure that `... - '40px' + "px"` is the kind of expression you want? (subtracting a string from a number...)

Comment: try just throwing in a hard coded value to test with.  And negative values will register as 0

Comment: So when subtracting a string from the scrollTop integer, it doesn't work, strange !

Comment: @EmilLundberg I would prefer it to be whatever the padding is because I am trying to get the padding to decrease as the user scrolls down the page.

Comment: I hope your complete code has the remaining `}` and `)`'s ;-)

Comment: @zachstarnes what I mean is that you're subtracting a string from a number. Is that really what you want to do?

Comment: `$(this).scrollTop() <= padding / 2` is always false: `'40px' / 2` is `NaN`, and any compaison involving `NaN` is false.

Comment: @adeneo getting rid of the `px` worked :) thanks

Comment: @zachstarnes - and preferably the quotes, you want a number, not a string.

Comment: @adeneo so having a `px` makes it a string?

Comment: @zachstarnes - no, quoting it makes it a string, removing anything but the numbers lets javascript use it as a number when needed (<- simple explanation), but you should remove the quotes, as you don't need a string, but a number.

Comment: To expand upon what @adeneo is saying: Although Javascript uses type coercion, storing numbers as strings can cause problems like `{var a = "40"; var b = 10; console.log( a+b );}` (try running that snippet in your console to see what happens for yourself).

Answer (score 2):

The following line does not result in something sensible

```
if ($(this).scrollTop() <= padding / 2) {
```

`padding` is a string. I have no clue what `"40px" / 2` would be, but I doubt javascript will make it 20px. Make padding an integer, and change it to `(padding / 2) + "px"`.